# Hair spawning in wrong direction

Tags: particles, normals, hair

I'm trying to model a bunny for learning purposes and I'm stuck on hair. After many tries I reworked my model and got almost satisfying effect. But I have one area where hairs (probably) are spawning in wrong direction. This happens only on top of legs.

Particles (I moved them so they're all up, thought it would at least make them visible):
[image: Particles]

Faces and normals visible:
[image: Faces and normals]

Look of hairs in object mode:
[image: No hair]

After flipping normals:
[image: Hair, but wrong direction]