# Weird default hair particles growth direction

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to create my first model in blender and I've decided to start with a relatively simple low-poly spider model. When I started to make fur on its legs and added hair particles, I noticed that some strands are facing wrong direction, even inside of the mesh sometimes:

[image: spider leg fur]

The only solution I've managed to find online was to flip normals, but my normals are all right:

[image: spider leg normals]

The object has the rotation and scale applied. I doubt that manually combing the wrong growing fur is an option. My problem seems to be of one nature with [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186503/hair-spawning-in-wrong-direction). I wonder what causes this issue and would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix or avoid it.

Here's the .blend file with the leg from the screenshot [image]

Comment: I'm not an expert with hair, so I don't really know what's going on, but it might help others if you could upload your blender file so they could take a closer look at it.  Here's how to upload blender files to your post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file

Comment: Hair rotation is initially based on UV rotation, you might check your UV unwrap.

Comment: @AllenSimpson Thanks for your answer, but could you please specify what exactly should I fix in my UV unwrap? Its stretching visualization is all blue/greenish-blue so I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46831/why-do-i-have-bald-spots-with-hair-particlesystem

Comment: @aky-her thanks, it is related indeed, but there's no answer given about what causes this issue. I'd like to remove the source of the problem and avoid it in the future. And adding more hair manually doesn't seem like an elegant solution to me, because it involves particle editing and if I'd like to make some emission tweaks in the future, I'd have to repeat all the manual regrowing again and again, which I'd like to be (and I believe it is supposed to) done automatically.